# how to write a regular expression to match a small part of a repeating pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following pattern to match :

```
(10,'more random stuff 21325','random stuff','2014-10-26 04:50:23','','uca-default-u-kn','page')
```

For some context, it's part of a larger file , which contains many similar patterns separated by commas :

```
(10,'more random stuff 21325','random stuff','2014-10-26 04:50:23','','uca-default-u-kn','page'),
(11,'more random stuff 1nyny5','random stuff','2014-10-26 04:50:23','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),
(14,'more random stuff 21dd5','random stuff','2014-10-26 04:50:23','','uca-default-u-kn','page')
```

my goal is to ditch all patterns ending with 'page' and to keep the rest. For that, I'm trying to use
regular expressions to identify those patterns. Here is the one I come out with for now :

```
"\(.*?,\'page\'\)"
```

However, it's not working as expected.
In the following python code, I use this regex, and replace every match with an empty string :

```
import re

txt = "(10,'Redirects_from_moves','*..2NN:,@2.FBHRP:D6ܽ�','2014-10-26 04:50:23','','uca-default-u-kn','page'),"
txt += "(11,'Redirects_with_old_history','*..2NN:,@2.FBHRP:D6ܽ�','2010-08-26 22:38:36','','uca-default-u-kn','page'),"
txt += "(12,'Unprintworthy_redirects','*..2NN:,@2.FBHRP:D6ܽ�','2010-08-26 22:38:36','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),"
txt += "(13,'Anarchism','random_stuff','2020-01-23 13:27:44',' ','uca-default-u-kn','page'),"
txt += "(14,'Anti-capitalism','random_stuff','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),"
txt += "(15,'Anti-fascism','*D*L.8:NB\r�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),"
txt += "(16,'Articles_containing_French-language_text','*D*L.8:NB\r�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','page'),"
txt += "(17,'Articles_containing_French-language_text','*D*L.8:NB\r�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','page')"

new_txt = re.sub("\(.*?,\'page\'\)", "",txt)
```

I was expecting that new_text would contains all patterns ending with 'subcat', and remove all
patterns ending with 'page', however, I obtain :

`new_txt = ,,,,`

What's happening here ? How can I change my regex to obtain the desired result ?

Comment: Yes, it happens because `.` can match any char.

Comment: I was expecting the part ".*?" to match any char, but as few as possible, because of the "?" . It's mostly what confuses me.

Comment: No, `.*?` matches as few as possible **up to the subsequent subpattern match**. So, the matches will be as long as necessary up to the `,\'page\'\)` match. Strings are parsed from left to right.

Comment: You are concatenating the string, and the remove all till the the first occurrence of `'page')` See https://regex101.com/r/46z6mX/1

Comment: I see, thank you both for your explanations I see what's wrong with my regular expression now :)

Comment: So, the question is how "messy" your data are. If there can be `)`, `(`, `),(` inside the string fields, you need to describe the field syntax. Something like `new_txt = re.sub(r",?\((?:(?:\d+|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'),)+'page'\)", "",txt, flags=re.S).strip(',')` ([demo here](https://ideone.com/9gsReF)) (there is still an edge case I did not account for here). Or use the workaround posted below.

Comment: that was a concern of mine too. There is one part in my data where ')' or '(' could appear, as it's wikipedia article titles basically. '),(' is much more unlikely but not impossible.

Comment: There is a better approach if you can get these tuples as separate lines. Then, you could simply split with `\n`, and use `ast.literal_eval` and check the last item. `[x for x in lines if ast.literal_eval(x)[-1] != 'page']`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/84VEXN).

Comment: I think separating the tuples is the best approach, however I need to figure out how to do. I'm going ask a new question related to that where I'll explain better the structure of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We might be tempted to do a regex replacement here, but that would basically always leave open edge cases, as @Wiktor has correctly pointed out in a comment below.  Instead, a more foolproof approach is to use `re.findall` and simply extract every tuple with does not end in `'page'`.  Here is an example:

```py
parts = re.findall(r"\(\d+,'[^']*?'(?:,'[^']*?'){4},'(?!page')[^']*?'\),?", txt)
print(''.join(parts))
```

This prints:

> (12,'Unprintworthy_redirects','*..2NN:,@2.FBHRP:D6ܽ�','2010-08-26 22:38:36','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),(14,'Anti-capitalism','random_stuff','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),(15,'Anti-fascism','*D*L.8:NB�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),

The regex pattern used above just matches a leading number, followed by 5 singly quoted terms, and then a sixth singly quoted term which is *not* `'page'`.  Then, we string join the tuples in the list output to form a string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're giving me a workout today `:-)`.  Fixed it.

Comment: great work ! There's one case where I still have an issue, it's when there's quotes in between, for example, "(15,'Anti-fa'scism','*D*L.8:NB\r�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat')," is not matched because of the quote in 'Anti-fa'scism'

Comment: @nathanraynal That's a real nightmare of an edge case.  I don't have a workaround for that, but then again, that's not the question you asked.

Comment: true, I wanted to ask a separate question for this issue. For some contexts, it's wikipedia articles titles so sadly quotes are frequents and I must find a way to deal with them. However I think I'll accept your answer as it does more than what I ask for already :).

Comment: You honestly might need some kind of parser here to fully cover all your edge cases.  Regex only goes so far, and only works well for well structured text.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that you concatenate the string, then then remove all until the first occurrence of `,'page')` leaving only the [trailing comma's](https://regex101.com/r/46z6mX/1).

Another workaround might be using a list of the strings, and join them with a newline instead of concatenating them.

Then use your pattern matching an optional comma and newline at the end to remove the line, leaving the ones that end with subcat

```
import re
lines = [
"(10,'Redirects_from_moves','*..2NN:,@2.FBHRP:D6ܽ�','2014-10-26 04:50:23','','uca-default-u-kn','page'),",
"(11,'Redirects_with_old_history','*..2NN:,@2.FBHRP:D6ܽ�','2010-08-26 22:38:36','','uca-default-u-kn','page'),",
"(12,'Unprintworthy_redirects','*..2NN:,@2.FBHRP:D6ܽ�','2010-08-26 22:38:36','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),",
"(13,'Anarchism','random_stuff','2020-01-23 13:27:44',' ','uca-default-u-kn','page'),",
"(14,'Anti-capitalism','random_stuff','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),",
"(15,'Anti-fascism','*D*L.8:NB\r�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),",
"(16,'Articles_containing_French-language_text','*D*L.8:NB\r�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','page'),",
"(17,'Articles_containing_French-language_text','*D*L.8:NB\r�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','page')"
]

new_txt = re.sub("\(.*,'page'\)(?:,\n)?", "", '\n'.join(lines))
print(new_txt)
```

Output

```
(12,'Unprintworthy_redirects','*..2NN:,@2.FBHRP:D6ܽ�','2010-08-26 22:38:36','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),
(14,'Anti-capitalism','random_stuff','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),
�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),
```

---

Or you can use a list comprehension to keep the lines that do not match the pattern.

```
result = [line for line in lines if not re.match(r"\(.*,'page'\),?$", line)]
print('\n'.join(result))
```

Output

```
(12,'Unprintworthy_redirects','*..2NN:,@2.FBHRP:D6ܽ�','2010-08-26 22:38:36','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),
(14,'Anti-capitalism','random_stuff','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),
�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','subcat'),
```

---

Another option to match the parts that end with `'page')` for the example data:

```
\(\d+,[^)]*(?:\)(?!,\s*\(\d+,)[^)]*)*,'page'\),?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(\d+,` Match `(` followed by 1+ digits and a comma
- `[^)]*` Optionally match any char except `)`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\)(?!,\s*\(\d+,)[^)]*` Only match a `)` when not directly followed by the pattern `,\s*\(\d+,` which matches the start of the parts in the example data
- `)*` Close group and optionally repeat
- `,'page'\),?` Match `,'page')` with an optional comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZAXyFR/1)

Comment: good approach too ! However, in my case, I don't have any simple method to get those separated strings, as I'm reading from a file.

Comment: @nathanraynal Not sure how efficient it would be, but you can read the file line by line, and then only keep the lines that do not match the pattern.

Comment: the thing is that a line contains many of those patterns, I still need a way to separate them to use your method, which is perfectly fine otherwise :)

Comment: @nathanraynal Ah, I see. Perhaps a pattern like this would also match `\(\d+,[^)]*(?:\)(?!,)[^)]*)*,'page'\),?` https://regex101.com/r/DU1CkU/1

Comment: works pretty well but I also have some issues with edge cases in this one, such as the line "(16,'Articles_contain(i),(ng_French-language_text','*D*L.8:NB\r�','2020-01-23 13:27:44','','uca-default-u-kn','page')," (the part "(i),( " seems to be the issue)

Comment: @nathanraynal It is kind of tricky, but this will match it `\(\d+,[^)]*(?:\)(?!,\s*\(\d+,)[^)]*)*,'page'\),?` https://regex101.com/r/ZAXyFR/1

Comment: Are you getting tired of endless edits?  Here, have a green one on the house `:-)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, your comment about a parser is a good one as this can easily break. You already had my vote in the first place :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird so the last one you gave seems to work perfectly ! I tried to break it adding randomly commas, parenthesis and quotes but had no success breaking it.

Comment: @Thefourthbird if you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @nathanraynal I have added it with an explanation about the pattern. It is Ok to keep Tim's solution as the accepted answer.